# Passing a Jquery variable to use in php script

Tags: php, jquery

I have a booking grid as shown below:

[image]

On this booking grid I have a dblClick event, which opens up a Jquery Dialog:

```
<div id="cp-bookings-dialog">

    <div class="cp-tiles-wrapper-dlg">

        <div class="cp-booking-info left">

            <p class="pno-margin">Booking Date: &nbsp;<strong>Booking Reference is = <? echo BookingDocket::get_bookref(); ?></strong></p>
            <p class="pno-margin">Return Date: &nbsp;<strong><? echo BookingDocket::get_bookdate(); ?></strong></p>
            <p class="pno-margin">Journey: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>
            <p class="pno-margin">Passenger Tel: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>
            <p class="pno-margin">E-mail: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>

        </div>

    </div>

 </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
    {
    var rowData = new Array();
        rowData = $("#bookings").getRowData(rowid);
        var brData = rowData['bookref'];

        getGridRow(brData);

        $("#cp-bookings-dialog").dialog({ hide: 'slide', height: 625, width: 733, title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ brData});
    },
```

Where brData is the 'Booking Reference' value that I want to use in my PHP script. At the moment this dblClick event is being sent to the following Ajax request:

```
function getGridRow(brData) {

   $.ajax({

    url: 'scripts/php/bootstrp/all.request.php',
    type: 'POST',

    data: {

        rowdata: brData,

        id: null,
        condition: null
    },
    dataType: 'text/xml',
    timeout: 20000,
    error: function(){
        alert("It failed");
        $('#cp-div-error').html('');
        $('#cp-div-error').append('<p>There was an error inserting the data, please try again later.</p>');
        $('#cp-div-error').dialog('open');
    },
    success: function(response){

        // Refresh page

        //response = brData;
        //alert(response);  <--- This alerts the correct Booking Reference

    }
});
```

Which gets sent to all.request.php

```
// Switch to determine method to call
switch ($_REQUEST['fnme']) {

case 'getDGRow':
header('Content-type: text/xml');
GetBookings::getGridRow($_REQUEST['rowdata']);
break;
```

And finally to the PHP script where I want to use this Jquery value:

```
class GetBookings {

public static function getGridRow($rowdata) {

    $rowdata = $_REQUEST['rowdata'];

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    try {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

            $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH); 

            {variables are all here}

        $stmt->closeCursor();

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
    }

    $dbh = null;

    }


    }
```

I'm not sure why, but this doesn't seem to be working. Also, just to note that when you dblClick a booking this opens a jQuery dialog box which displays all the details about the booking and is supposed to return all the results from `$query = "SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'";`

All I need to do is pass this data correctly and this will work as if I replace `$rowdata` with a booking reference value, this works as it should.

If anybody can help me with this, I will be very grateful as I've been trying to get this to work for quite some time now : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Look at your code:**

```
var rowData = new Array();
    rowData = $("#bookings").getRowData(rowid);
    var brData = rowData['bookref'];
```

The second line overwrited the first line, so you can delete `rowData = new Array()`.

Now, are you sure that `$_REQUEST['fnme']` exists? Your `switch` statement doesn't have any default value, and it looks like `getGridRow()` will never be executed.

Additionaly, `$rowdata = $_REQUEST['rowdata']` is meaningless, you can remove it.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: By changing this, the value brData is now 'undefined'

Comment: If so, I guess you can delete the first row and change the second row to your own. The first line doesn't have any meaning here. One more question - the issue you have is that the script doesn't alert anything? If so, just echo want you want to return from PHP's `getGridRow`

Comment: you would have to use rowData[0]['bookref'] but that is just a detail. only the rowData = new Array();  is needless and can be removed in his original code

Comment: @Asto, you're defenetly right, I wrote in my comment that the first line can be deleted. I'm waiting to change my answer, I don't want to just make my answer "solutionness"

Comment: Yeah I've removed that, it didn't have to be there

Comment: @nsilva great, you still didn't answer me - does `alert(response)` work?

Comment: Yes, this returns the Booking Reference of the row that is selected

Comment: @nsilva are you using the jQuery Grid Plugin? Are you **sure** the `rowid` provides the right value? Try to `alert(rowid)`, what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

why do you send it like

```
 data: {

    rowdata: 'fnme=getDGRow&row_data='+brData,

    id: null,
    condition: null
},
```

and not like

```
 data: {

    fname: 'getDGRow',
    rowdata: brData,

    id: null,
    condition: null
},
```

in the php file you can use `$_POST['fname']` and `$_POST['rowdata']` to grab the single values.

Currently, `$_REQUEST['rowdata']` is your entire string `'fnme=getDGRow&row_data='+brData`!

If you want to use the brData in your mysql query, try just using `$_REQUEST['row_data']` or use my example above to set the variable `$_REQUEST['rowdata']` correct.

---

your entire code as it should work

```
function getGridRow(brData) {

   $.ajax({

    url: 'scripts/php/bootstrp/all.request.php',
    type: 'POST',

    data: {

        fnme: 'getDGRow',
        rowdata: brData,

        id: null,
        condition: null
    },
    dataType: 'text/xml',
    timeout: 20000,
    error: function(){
        alert("It failed");
        $('#cp-div-error').html('');
        $('#cp-div-error').append('<p>There was an error inserting the data, please try again later.</p>');
        $('#cp-div-error').dialog('open');
    },
    success: function(response){

        // Refresh page

        //response = brData;
        alert(response); // <--- This alerts the correct Booking Reference

    }
});
```

-

```
// Switch to determine method to call
switch ($_REQUEST['fnme']) {

case 'getDGRow':
header('Content-type: text/xml');
GetBookings::getGridRow($_REQUEST['rowdata']);
break;
```

-

```
class GetBookings {

public function getGridRow($rowdata) {

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    try {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

            $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH); 

            {variables are all here}

        $stmt->closeCursor();

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
    }

    $dbh = null;

    }


    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I've made an edit to my code, basically I only need to pass the one value; rowdata: brData,

Comment: I've tried adding $_REQUEST['row_data'] to my query but that doesn't work either

Comment: now you don't send $_REQUEST['fnme'] and so you can't pass the switch case structure. edited my example too. To Debug it, echo the rowdata in your php script before the switch structure. you should see the correct brData value -- and remove $rowdata = $_REQUEST['rowdata']; from your getGridRow function, you want to pass it as parameter. overwriting it in the function can cause troubles while testing the script. passing the value as parameter should be enough

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've changed the code to this and added 'echo $rowdata;' to the GetBooking Class. In firebug console I can see this has displayed the correct value as it returns BR1274 which is the row I clicked. However, this is still not working, I'm not sure if it is because the dialog is loading before the PHP query is being made??

Comment: Would it help if I gave you the link to view this?

Comment: what is exactly not working? you get the right value inside the php function getGridRow()? your function has to return sth if you want to see something in the response of the ajax call --- as far as i know works the client side correct and there is only an error in your php function left? so we wouldn't need a link

Comment: In the Jquery Dialog I have "Booking Date: &nbsp;<strong>Booking Reference is = <? echo BookingDocket::get_bookref(); ?>", If I change $rowdata to BR12345 for example, it displays the booking reference, If I change it to $rowdata, it doesn't show any value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13657/discussion-between-nsilva-and-asto)

Comment: where do you call that, can't find it in the code above - maybe a link could be helpful. is this a new problem? passing the variable to your script via your ajax request works now? than you should consider to ask a new question to clear this up

Comment: If you go to http://www.marandy.com/onlinebookingv4/login.php --> Login --> Bookings, this is where the Grid is. The call is being made on the dblClick event, I've added the HTML to my original question

Comment: Just to add that at the moment, when the query is executed, $rowdata is empty, although if I echo $rowdata in the same query, the correct value shows in firebug console.

Comment: when echoing this line `$query = "SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'";`what does firebug say? is the $rowdata correct? if so, you should look about your prepared statements (but i've never worked with them in that way) --- i am in the chat online, still at work but will write there sometimes...